# How to dynamically display an array of arrays in groups

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to dynamically display an array of arrays. The nested array has multiple objects. I would like to display them in groups.

```
var obj = 
[
   [
     { name: 'Text 1', title: 'Text 1 Title', category: 'Text 1' },

     { name: 'Text 2', title: 'Text 2 Title', category: 'Text 1' }
   ],

   [
     { name: 'Text 1', title: 'Text 1 Title', category: 'Text 2' },

     { name: 'Text 2', title: 'Text 2 Title', category: 'Text 2' }
   ],
]
```

My original solution works but it displays it all in one line

```
const list = obj.map(cat => cat.map(e => {  
   return (
      <div className={e.category} key={`${e.title}-${e.name}`}>
         <h6>{e.title}</h6>
         <p>{e.name}</p>
      </div>
   )       
}));
```

e.g.

```
Name: Text 1
Title: Text 1 Title
Name: Text 2
Title: Text 2 Title
Name: Text 1
Title: Text 1 Title
Name: Text 2
Title: Text 2 Title
```

I would like to display them like this e.g.

```
Text 1 Category
Name: Text 1
Title: Text 1 Title
Name: Text 2
Title: Text 2 Title

Text 2 Category
Name: Text 1
Title: Text 1 Title
Name: Text 2
Title: Text 2 Title
```

I tried to create the category's in div and give them id and then render them but couldn't think of a solution to how to implement the category's in the right div

```
var objList = ["Text 1", "Text 2"];

const sectionList = objList.map((e, index) => {
   return (
      <div id={e} key={index}></div>
   )
})
```

Comment: Is it by accident that they are already grouped in the sub array by category or is the data like this per default?

Comment: Please choose a better example, as this one doesn't illustrate the expected behaviour properly (or clearly enough)

Comment: @TobiasTengler it is not by accident, each sub array will be its own category and then the objects inside is the content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Remake your obj

```
const reArray = {};

obj.forEach(parent => {
    parent.forEach(child => {
        const {name, title, category} = child;
        if(reArray[category]) {
            reArray[category].push({name, title})
        } else {
            reArray[category]=[{name,title}]
        }
    })
})
```

#### render

```
Object.keys(reArray).map(obj => {
    return (
        <div key={obj}>
            <h6>{obj} Category</h6>
            {reArray[obj].map(item => {
                const {name, title} = item;
                return (
                    <>
                        <p>Name :{name}</p>
                        <p>Title : {title}</p>
                    </>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
})
```

Comment: what is test? its undefined

Comment: It is my mistake. It is `reArray`

Comment: thank you very much, it works, exactly how i wanted it.
but can you explain this 
if(reArray[category]) {
                    reArray[category].push({writer, title})
                } else {
                    reArray[category]=[{writer,title}]
                }

Comment: If there was `Text 1` key in `reArray`, I pushed  child object to that key's value. But if there was no `Text 1`  key in `reArray`,  I made a new arrangement with child, and I declared that as the value of `Text 1`.